# Bryntum Scheduler React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, bryntum-scheduler

I succeeded to find some functions about the different actions possibles but I still need the others functions:

Actually I have theses functions that i pass directly as the props on the Scheduler React Component:

onBeforeEventSave
onAfterEventDrop
onBeforePaste
onEventResizeEnd

I need the others functions like when the event can move to the right or to the left with the edit menu, or when the event is divided and the most important I need to have the function when the event is deleted.

Other thing, I could to know how make some dates for a particular user disabled with a custom field (day off)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create your own classes based on the component class implementation and create or custom function and pass the event to them.

```
import { DragHelper } from'https://www.bryntum.com/examples/build/scheduler.module.js?449865';

class Drag extends DragHelper {}
```

And then you can create your custom functions